# jpa project deployment to Jboss gives Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper

Tags: jpa, wildfly-8

I am deploying my JPA project to wildfly 8.2 server. its giving me exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper
```

Can someone put some light on it..

i have created Provider

```
@Provider
public class EJBExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Exception>
{

    public Response toResponse(Exception exception) {
        return Response.status(500).build();
    }

}
```

But still the error is there.

Answer (score 3):

I was using WildFly 8.2.0 with EclipseLink 2.5.2

That's why it was causing..

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper from [Module "org.eclipse.persistence:main"
```

To solve this line

```
<module name="javax.ws.rs.api"/>
```

needs to be included in Wildfly installation  modules/system/layers/base/org/eclipse/persistence/main/module.xml file..

This solved the problem for me..

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-UsingEclipseLink

Answer (score 0):

check this below  link may be will helpful for  you:

http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/06/03/exception-handling-in-jax-rs-resteasy-with-exceptionmapper/

Comment: I have done the same thing as mentioned in the link. But the error is still there i guess the system is not able to find the annoated Mapper class.